# Differences between javascript inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Why do some people use

`subclass.prototype = Object.create(superclass.prototype);`

and others

`subclass.prototype = superclass.prototype;`

One uses the class while the other creates an instance of the class before attaching it to the prototype of the subclass. Which one is the correct way to do inheritance?

Comment: See this article that goes over `Object.Create` - [Object.create(): the New Way to Create Objects in JavaScript](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/object.create-the-new-way-to-create-objects-in-javascript.html)

Comment: @Bergi just saw my mistake, I deleted the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is correct. The second one means that the two "classes" have the same prototype chain, so `superclass` won't even appear in the prototype chain for instances of subclass.